# wsimport by setting https.protocol to TLSv1.2

Tags: java, web-services, wsimport, tls1.2

I want to import a web service using wsdl. The server is using TLSv1.2.

Using java code I connect to the server by setting `System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");`

How do I do the same while using wsimport? I'm using Java 1.7.0_65.

When I tried  `wsimport <wsdl-url>` I'm getting

```
parsing WSDL...


[ERROR] Received fatal alert: protocol_version

Failed to read the WSDL document: https://<server-name>/Test/Test/Transform?wsdl, because 1) could not find the document; /2) the document cou
ld not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <wsdl:definitions>.


[ERROR] failed.noservice=Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s):

 At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.


    Failed to parse the WSDL.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java" -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\lib\tools.jar" -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsImport -keep -verbose https://<server-name>/Test/Test/Transform?wsdl
```

Comment: There is a better way to do it with wsimport! (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

SET **JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS** first!

```
set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

then, execute **wsimport** as usual